# Topia Term Extract - Italian Lexicon

Tags: python, nlp, pos-tagger

I'm looking for a tool to extract topic keywords from text. Topia seems to be a good solutions, anyway it does not came with an italian-lexicon file.

Searching on the web i couldn't find a precompiled file, so I guess I need to build my own. Does anyone have suggestion on how to build it without spending a lifetime?

The english file is formatted like this:

```
images NNS
psychiatric JJ
Hope NNP NN VB VBP
elimination NN
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLP resources for Italian:

- http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Resources_for_Italian

Of special interest to you are the lexicons and taggers.

Another lexicon:

- http://aune.lpl.univ-aix.fr/projects/multext/LEX/LEX.SmpIt.html